# How to remove background color of text highlight on vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

Currently I have the follow line code:

[image: End function hint example]

As you can see, the text "fn main" is like a hint from rust-analyzer extension, I would like to remove or change the background color. This happens also on type hint when I declare variables.

[image: Types hint example]

Comment: Does this help? https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#color-configurations

Comment: Check out this. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/rust

Comment: Thanks you @isaactfa, now I changed the color :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about changing the colors but the options to toggle them on/off are under the **Inlay Hints** section in extension settings.